# Set style for Expandable List

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I want to set new style for expandable list view in my Android app. I am creating a *group_indicator.xml* file in drawable folder, where I am writing the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_empty="true" android:drawable="@drawable/arrowright1">
    <item android:state_expanded="true" android:drawable="@drawable/arrowdown1">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrowright1">
</item></item></item></selector>
```

Then I am using this XML file in my `ExpandableList` view in the main file:

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ExpandableListView>
```

Now I want to set some more styles for my expandable list, I want to change the appearance of the parent and the child nodes.

Is there any other way to do that? 
I heard of some *style.xml* file in `res->values` folder, but I don't know exactly how to implement it.
Please Guide.

Comment: What do you mean by appearance is it simple text style and color or something else?

Comment: In simple expandable list, we have text with an arrow. Its just simple implementation of expandable list. I want to customize it with some better views. Though i have done this with simple way, but i would like to have your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use implement custom [ExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html)

Override the following methods:

[getChildView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html#getChildView%28int,%20int,%20boolean,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) to override child view and inflate your own custom view.
[getGroupView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html#getGroupView%28int,%20boolean,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) to override group header view and inflate your own custom view.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ExpandableListView#setGroupIndicator(Drawable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setGroupIndicator%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) method. it worked for me. hope it wil help you.